# slect dropdown value, that checks checkbox and fills out input

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Desired behavior:**

1.Select "sweets" for *field1*

2. the that will pre check values that have the same value as pre-selcted *field1*
3. if checkbox is checked it should trigger the input field to print out 
   strings that were checked
   ex. if value "a" is checked then is should display "a" in the input
4. if "sweets" is checked in *field1* then *field3* will populate with value

I have everything working except item 3. unless i check the items myself then they will display in the input. 
I can not hard code any of the values in because the values will be dynamically brought in.

Below i have a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/kfb4nc03

```js
document.getElementById('field1').onchange = function() {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].checked = boxes[i].value == this.value;

    $checks = $(":checkbox");
    $checks.on('change', function() {
      var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i, v) {
        return this.value;
      }).get().join(" ,");
      $('#field_results').val(string);
    });


    document.getElementById("field3").value = this.value;
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='field1' id="field1">

  <option value="1">Fruits</option>
  <option value="2">Vegetables</option>
  <option value="3">Sweets</option>
  <option value="4">Meat</option>
</select>


<div id='changer'>

  <input type='checkbox' id='a' value="3" /><label>A</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='b' value="3" /><label>B</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='c' value="3" /><label>C</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='d' value="3" /><label>D</label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="field_results" /><br>


<select name='field3' id="field3">

  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need move to out of change event `$checks.on('change', function() {})` at this function the checked value still not work and change to `this.id` instead of `this.value` if you want to display a,b,c,d.

```js
document.getElementById('field1').onchange = function() {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].checked = boxes[i].value == this.value;

    $checks = $(":checkbox");
    $checks.on('change', function() {
      
    });

    var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i, v) {
        return $(this).next("label").html();
        //return this.id;
      }).get().join(" ,");
      
      $('#field_results').val(string);

    document.getElementById("field3").value = this.value;
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='field1' id="field1">

  <option value="1">Fruits</option>
  <option value="2">Vegetables</option>
  <option value="3">Sweets</option>
  <option value="4">Meat</option>
</select>


<div id='changer'>

  <input type='checkbox' id='a' value="3" /><label>A</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='b' value="3" /><label>B</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='c' value="3" /><label>C</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='d' value="3" /><label>D</label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="field_results" /><br>


<select name='field3' id="field3">

  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hien this works really great. what if i wanted to use the text?

Comment: you can use $(this).next("label").html(), i updated answer

Comment: hey hein worked great on my fiddle example but its not working  on my code im getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: this.html is not a function

Comment: i see my problem, since i have an aspx checkbox its formed a little differently:<div class="checkbox"><label for="field2"><input id="field2" type="checkbox" name="field2" value="1"> a</label></div> do i need: $(this).next("input").next("label").html()

Comment: you should not wrap input tag inside label tag

Comment: i unfortunately dont have that option, tht is how it is pre built

Comment: there is for your requirement https://jsfiddle.net/viethien/s9mqu0dr/2/

Comment: did you check jsfiddle.net/viethien/s9mqu0dr/2? is it your requirement?

Comment: Hey Hein this worked great! thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the event handler for the checkboxes from the event handler for the dropdowns. Additionally, you should try to stick to either using jquery or not using jquery.

```js
var $checks = $(":checkbox");

document.getElementById('field1').onchange = function() {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].checked = boxes[i].value == this.value;
    $checks.change();
    document.getElementById("field3").value = this.value;
  }
};

$checks.on('change', function() {
  var string = $checks.filter(":checked").map(function(i, v) {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(" ,");
  $('#field_results').val(string);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='field1' id="field1">

  <option value="1">Fruits</option>
  <option value="2">Vegetables</option>
  <option value="3">Sweets</option>
  <option value="4">Meat</option>
</select>


<div id='changer'>

  <input type='checkbox' id='a' value="3" /><label>A</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='b' value="3" /><label>B</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='c' value="3" /><label>C</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='d' value="3" /><label>D</label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="field_results" /><br>


<select name='field3' id="field3">

  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this

```
return $(this).next('label').text();
```

You have two problems

1) your `oncheck` event should be outside the on-change event

2) your label lives outside checkbox so if you want to get text of it you need to get by using `next` or `closest`.

```js
document.getElementById('field1').onchange = function() {
  var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].checked = boxes[i].value == this.value;   

    document.getElementById("field3").value = this.value;
  }
};

 $(":checkbox").on('change', function() {    
      var string = $(":checkbox").filter(":checked").map(function(i, v) {
        return $(this).next('label').text();
      }).get().join(" ,");
      $('#field_results').val(string);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='field1' id="field1">

  <option value="1">Fruits</option>
  <option value="2">Vegetables</option>
  <option value="3">Sweets</option>
  <option value="4">Meat</option>
</select>


<div id='changer'>

  <input type='checkbox' id='a' value="3" /><label>A</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='b' value="3" /><label>B</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='c' value="3" /><label>C</label><br />
  <input type='checkbox' id='d' value="3" /><label>D</label>
</div>

<input type="text" id="field_results" /><br>


<select name='field3' id="field3">

  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```